# Quickly selecting all edges from a cut out face from knife tool?

Tags: vertices

is there a way to quickly select all the verticles after cutting it out with kniife tool? instead of 1 vertex at a time selection

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you hit enter to accept the cut, all of the vertices made during the cut are already selected.  Do you you mean you want to select that set of vertices again later?

Comment: yeah this is what I mean, because if i move the selection and then later find i want to move it again, how can i do the selection quickly?

Comment: immediately after you make the knife cut, go to your object's Data Properties (the tab with the triangle) click the + under Vertex Groups and then click assign.  You'll get a new vertex group with the selected vertices in it.  Change the name so you'll remember it.  Later, in edit mode you can click that group and then the Select button to select that set of vertices.